# How to add Buttons on top of the carousel container that remains constant while the carousel images change?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel how would I add Buttons over the container that remain unchanged while the images change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to put em outside of the div with the `owl-stage` class.

You could then use [css positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to position buttons or a div containing buttons above the carousel.

Mind that some carousels sets the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to a high value, so you might need to overrule this by setting a higher [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) on your positioned buttons.